# #imageresizer azure web site app

Tags: .net, azure, imageresizer

I'm reviewing #ImageResizer right now, and I want to use it with a .NET website that is hosted in Azure Web Site application.  The issue is that I have a very limited access to the web.config file and cannot make the web.config changes referenced in your documentation.

Do you have a solution for using #imageresizer with Azure Web Site App?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of Azure Web Sites having any restrictions on Web.config. I've used ImageResizer on Azure web sites, but can't recommend it. If you're going with Azure, I'd suggest a dedicated VM or a Cloud Service backed by reserved instances. You really do NOT want to run image processing on a CPU-metered service.

Here is my experience with using Azure Web Sites:
http://www.nathanaeljones.com/blog/2014/azure